# $U,V\subseteq X^\omega$ and X is w.o. such that $U'\subseteq U$ and $V'\subseteq V$ open and $U'\cap V'=\emptyset$ and $U'\cup V'=U\cup V$

Tags: general-topology, set-theory

Suppose $U,V\subseteq X^\omega$ (where $X^\omega:=\{f| f:\omega\to X\}$) and X is wellorderable, how it would be possible to show that there are open sets $U'\subseteq U$ and $V'\subseteq V$ such that $U'\cap V'=\emptyset$ and $U'\cup V'=U\cup V$.

Some preliminary remarks:

- $X^\omega:=\{f| f:\omega\to X\}$ (the set of all infinite sequences drawn from X)
- Let $X^{<\omega}:=\displaystyle\bigcup_{n\in\omega}\{f | f : n \to X\}$ (the set of all finite sequences you drawn from X)
- Given an arbitrary finite sequence $s\in X^{<\omega}$, define **N**$_s:=\{a\in X^\omega|s\subset a\}$. For each $s\in X^{<\omega}$, **N**$_s$ is a basic open set, in fact:
- If $U$ is an open set, then there exists $\mathcal{A}\subseteq X^{<\omega}$ such that $U=\displaystyle\bigcup_{s\in \mathcal{A}}$**N**$_s$.
- It's easy to show that each **N**$_s$ is a clopen set (both open and closed).

Well, of course $\omega=\mathbb{N}$.

Another remark is worth: it should be important that $X$ is well-orderable, but it doesn't really matter whether we are working with or without the Axiom of Choice, in fact in this setting it is possible to prove that if X is well-orderable, then there is a choice function for collection of non-empty open subsets of $X^\omega$, and a choice function for collection of non-empty closed subsets of $X^\omega$.

Comment: What is $\omega$ ? What have you tried ?

Comment: And what is the topology on $X^\omega$?

Comment: I added some details. The procedure I imagined to solve it is using another property I proved before, namely that for each open set $U$, there is a set $\mathcal{A}\subseteq X^{<\omega}$ such that $A$ is an antichain and $U=\displaystyle\cup_{s\in \mathcal{A}}$*N*$_s$. Hence, all the *N*$_s$ for $s\in A$ are pairwise disjoint.